# Tabularx that includes math won't compile for rows containing exponents

Tags: tabularx

I have a tabularx table that will not compile unless I comment out all the rows that contain exponents. I must be missing a typo, right?

Here is the most I could reduce it:

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ l | X }
\hline  
\multicolumn{2}{l}{stuff} \\
\hline
\texttt{x: array(1..h, 1..n, 1..m) of mpvar} & \(x\) \\
\texttt{y_r: array(1..h, 1..n, 1..(m-1)) of mpvar} & \(y^r \) \\  % Compiles if you comment out these lines
\texttt{y_d: array(1..h, 1..(n-1), 1..m) of mpvar} &  \(y^d \)    %
\end{tabularx}
 
\end{document}
```

The same behavior occurs if I use dollar signs instead of parentheses.

Comment: It's not the exponents, it's the underscore: that's a math-mode command to make subscripts. I guess you want `\texttt{t\_r ...}`.

Comment: This works, although I don't understand why. That column isn't in math mode, right? Or does `\texttt` put you in math mode?

Comment: No, the underscore `_`  is allowed _only_ in math mode. And since you are not in math mode, you get an error.

Comment: @Max - Observe the difference between `\texttt{y_r: array...` and `\texttt{y\_r: array...`.

Comment: the example can be simplified to  `\documentclass[12pt]{article}\begin{document}\texttt{y_r}\end{document} `

Comment: Thank you. But now it also won't compile if there are subscripts in the math expressions in the right column.

Comment: @Max - It sounds like you're replacing `_` with `\_` in the second column. Is that the case?

Comment: It turned out I missed one in the left column :) FWIW, the reason I expected to be able to use underscores inside `\texttt` was that if you search this site for "inline verbatim", that is the top suggestion. But clearly `\texttt` isn't really a verbatim, just a cue to change to a monospace font.

Comment: @Max - For inline verbatim mode, you should write `\verb+y_r: array(1..h, 1..n, 1..(m-1)) of mpvar+`, *not* `\texttt{y_r: array(1..h, 1..n, 1..(m-1)) of mpvar}`. (Here, `+` can be any character that doesn't occur *inside* the verbatim string.) Put differently, there's a lot more to inline verbatim mode than just switching to a monospaced font face.